# System.import not processing in karma-test-shim.js

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am setting up Karma for an Angular 2 app. The System.import in my karma-test-shim.js is throwing an error and I believe it is because I am importing incorrectly what I put in karma.conf.js.

My karma.conf.js (trimmed down):

```
'use strict';

var argv = require('yargs').argv;

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js',
  // System.js for module loading
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

  // Zone.js dependencies
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',

  // Paths loaded via module imports
  { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

  { pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'app/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},
],
// Proxied base paths
proxies: {},
exclude: [
  'node_modules/**/*spec.js'
],
reporters: ['mocha'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
autoWatch: false,
// TODO: Remove sandbox. This is just work around for Chrome issue
// https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/73#issuecomment-236597429
browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeNoSandbox: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
singleRun: true,

// Command line args for tests
client: {
  files: argv.files
    }
  });
};
```

My karma-test-shim.js:

```
// Turn on full stack traces in errors to help debugging
Error.stackTraceLimit=Infinity;


jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// // Cancel Karma's synchronous start,
// // we will call `__karma__.start()` later, once all the specs are loaded.
__karma__.loaded = function() {};


System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/app': {
      defaultExtension: false,
      format: 'register',
      map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).
            filter(onlyAppFiles).
            reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
              var moduleName = appPath.replace(/^\/base\/app\//, './').replace(/\.js$/, '');
              pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath]
              return pathsMapping;
            }, {})

      }
    }
});

Promise.all([
  System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
  System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
])
  // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
  .then(([testing, testingBrowser]) => {
    // testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    //   testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    //   testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    // );
    testing.setBaseTestProviders(testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
      testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
  })
  // Then we find all the tests.
  .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
  // And load the modules.
  .then(context => context.keys().map(context))
  // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);


function filePath2moduleName(filePath) {
  return filePath.
           replace(/^\//, '').              // remove / prefix
           replace(/\.\w+$/, '');           // remove suffix
}


function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
  return /\/base\/app\/(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/.test(filePath);
}


function onlySpecFiles(path) {
  return /spec\.js$/.test(path);
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
24 11 2016 18:19:31.954:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /@angular/core/testing /
24 11 2016 18:19:31.954:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /@angular/core/testing
24 11 2016 18:19:31.956:WARN [web-server]: 404: /@angular/core/testing
24 11 2016 18:19:31.958:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing /
24 11 2016 18:19:31.959:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
24 11 2016 18:19:31.962:WARN [web-server]: 404: /@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "originalErr": {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your karma-test-shim.js is prob wrong, you need to change the map

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: {'testing': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}},

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});
```

**strong text**